# How can I add diffrent editable text fields?

Tags: php, customization, custom-field, text

I am new to Wordpress development and created my own theme in php.
My problem is, that I don´t realy know how to achieve the following:
The website has diffrent areas, where custom text shall appear.
This text shall be editable in the front end.
At first I tried to use the normal page editor, but then I only have one editable area.
My website for example has in the  tag some text(that i want to be editable), then some content like pictures or other stuff(doesnt need to be editable) and then some custom text again.
So I need to add diffrent areas of text on many diffrent pages.
How can I achieve this?

From my own research I found the plugin "Custom Fields", but I don´t realy know if that is way to go. As wordpress is a cms, I think there must be more options than installing an external tool for that.

I´m thankful for any help.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell from a general description, but it sounds like you might be able to create a widgetized area (or areas) called a sidebar. You can register the sidebar in `functions.php`, then call it in one of your template files, and users can manage what shows in them in the Themes > Widgets screen.

Comment: if your theme was a block based theme then the canonical answer would be to use the site editor interface, then to lock the areas that are not intended to be editable. For legacy themes widget areas and nav menus was the default answer, though if you install a plugin to add a new type of area with its own interface then you will need to ask that plugins support or other users of that plugin (3rd party plugin/theme dev support questions are offtopic here)